# Can I export a GCloud drive image to store locally and restore later?

Tags: gcloud

Can I export a GCloud drive image to store locally and restore later ?
I need to save money for drives that I most rarely use.
Seems the SSD-Drives amass the bulk costs that I need to avoid without deleting the disks.

Regards,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) includes all the steps to export a disk image to Google Cloud Storage, then you can download the image from here to your local machine.

In order to achieve this basically you have to export your image either by using the following  gcloud command or by navigating the Cloud Console going into Images > selecting details > export and following the process

gcloud compute images export 
--destination-uri destination-uri 
--image image-name

Hope this helps